# Creating an Office 2010 sidebar like menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, wpf-controls

I'm relatively new at WPF and I've finally started making my first application with navigation.
However I'm stuck at one particular thing. I'd love to create a vertical menu like the one in the Office 2010 sidebar. Like this (nb, I'm not interested in a ribbon to go with that, just a simple menu):

[image]

Which has a hover effect like this:

[image]

I guess this is probably a walk in the park for those good at XAML, however I'm stuck, stuck as can be, I've tried googling, tried getting it in Blend and VS but I'm stuck.

I don't need the triangle on the right, just a square "button" with a hover like the one seen above would make me a really happy camper.

So, any hints and pointers as to what I should look for or read up on?

What I have so far (however I'm not sure it's even right) is this:

```
        <Button Content="Choice One!" Margin="204,153,231,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
    <Button Content="Choice One!" Margin="204,191,231,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleY="1.09" ScaleX="1"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-179.963" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="0.045"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFCACACA" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

All help is appreciated. :)

//JaggenSWE

Comment: Do you have any existing XAML to work with?

Comment: Sorry, I added that now.